# Can you make a view that redirects the user to another app based on a random variable?

Tags: django, django-views

as the title says, I want to create a functions that redirects the user to another app based on a random variable.

I created a function and gave a random value to a variable that calls the corresponding view of another app, but only the first value of the random range works fine, while the other get an error at the form validation.

contest.views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
import random
from user.models import UserProfileInfo

from .problems.problem5_1contest.views import problem_one
from .problems.problem5_2contest.views import problem_two
from .problems.problem5_3contest.views import problem_three

def contestproblem1(request):
    return problem_one(request)
def contestproblem2(request):
    return problem_two(request)
def contestproblem3(request):
    return problem_three(request)

def contest(request):
    k = random.randint(1,3)
    if(k == 1):
        return contestproblem1(request)
    if(k == 2):
        return contestproblem2(request)
    if(k == 3):
        return contestproblem3(request)
```

problem5_1contest.views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .forms import ProblemOneForm
from .models import ProblemOneContest

from user.models import UserProfileInfo
# Create your views here.

def wrong(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_1contest/wrong.html')

def correct(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_1contest/correct.html')


def problem_one(request):
    form = ProblemOneForm()
    form.fields['first'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['second'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['solution'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProblemOneForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            if(int(form.cleaned_data['answer']) == int(form.cleaned_data['solution'])):
                return render(request, 'problem5_1contest/correct.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'problem5_1contest/wrong.html')
        else:
            print('ERROR')

    return render(request, 'problem1/problem1.html',{ 'form':form } )
```

problem5_2contest.views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .forms import ProblemTwoForm
from .models import ProblemTwoContest

from user.models import UserProfileInfo
# Create your views here.

def wrong(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_2contest/wrong.html')

def correct(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_2contest/correct.html')


def problem_two(request):
    form = ProblemTwoForm()
    form.fields['solution'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProblemTwoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            if(int(form.cleaned_data['answer']) == int(form.cleaned_data['solution'])):
                return render(request, 'problem5_2contest/correct.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'problem5_2contest/wrong.html')
        else:
            print('ERROR')

    return render(request, 'problem2/problem2.html',{ 'form':form } )
```

problem5_3contest.views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .forms import ProblemThreeForm
from .models import ProblemThreeContest

from user.models import UserProfileInfo
# Create your views here.

def wrong(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_3contest/wrong.html')

def correct(request):
    return render(request, 'problem5_3contest/correct.html')


def problem_three(request):
    form = ProblemThreeForm()

    form.fields['first_digit_one'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['first_digit_two'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    form.fields['second_digit_one'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['second_digit_two'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['second_digit_three'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    form.fields['third_digit_one'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['third_digit_two'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    form.fields['answer_digit_one'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['answer_digit_two'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    form.fields['answer_digit_three'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProblemThreeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            if(int(form.cleaned_data['answer']) != int(form.cleaned_data['answer_digit_one']) + int(form.cleaned_data['answer_digit_two']) + int(form.cleaned_data['answer_digit_three'])):
                return render(request, 'problem5_3contest/wrong.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'problem5_3contest/correct.html')
        else:
            print('ERROR')

    return render(request, 'problem3/problem3.html',{ 'form':form } )
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from user import views
from classes.views import class5, class6, class7, class8, classes

from contest.views import contest


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pwa.urls')),
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',views.user_login,name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('home/', views.index, name='home'),
    path('classes/', classes, name='classes'),
    path('class5/', class5, name='class5'),
    path('class6/', class6, name='class6'),
    path('class7/', class7, name='class7'),
    path('class8/', class8, name='class8'),

    path('contest/', contest, name='contest'),

]
```

contest.urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from contest.problems.problem5_1contest.views import problem_one as contestproblem1
from contest.problems.problem5_2contest.views import problem_two as contestproblem2
from contest.problems.problem5_3contest.views import problem_three as contestproblem3

urlpatterns = [
    path('contest/class5/problemone', contestproblem1),
    path('contest/class5/problemtwo', contestproblem2),
    path('contest/class5/problemthree', contestproblem3),
]
```

Comment: Please start by showing your code and clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added my code, sorry if it is to long.

Comment: What is exactly the error that you are getting ?

Comment: The form loads, but after I submit the data it "refreshes" the form as an empty one. Also the forms are saved in the data base.

Comment: in which view ?

Comment: I believe it is in the problems views

Comment: Please add  `urls.py` and specify which url is trigerring the error in browser

Comment: The problem is  path('contest/', contest, name='contest'),

Comment: I guess I found the error. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything when the form is not valid.

```
def problem_one(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        print('ERROR')
    ...
```

```
def problem_two(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        print('ERROR')
    ...
```

```
def problem_three(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
    else:
        print('ERROR')
    ...
```

Instead of just printing `ERROR`, you should return something that can be like `return render(request, 'wrong.html', {'error: 'The form is invalid'})`

If you don't return anything, you will get this error, which I assume to be the one you are getting.

> The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Comment: I am not getting an actual error, it is more like when you create another form before displaying the first one. Maybe it helps if I explain what i want to do on a larger scale: I want to create a "loop" with problems that the user has to solve.